# is there `on duplicate key insert` in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, unique-constraint

I am learning MySQL and used the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, what this does, if I am not mistaken, when it found a duplicate; it will update the row. So, to my question, is there something like `ON DUPLICATE KEY INSERT`? like when it found a duplicate, it will still insert the data into the table?

Comment: The "insert ... on duplicate key" fires the "update" *when* the row can not be inserted into the database, because the attempt to add a row violated a UNIQUE KEY constraint. If you mean that if an INSERT raises a duplicate key exceptio, you want the INSERT to automatically be retried using different values that would not violate the UNIQUE constraint, then no, there is no builtin MySQL functionality to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to insert a row that has duplicate values in columns that are constrained against duplicate values. If you could, the result would be that the database would be in a state that violates its own constraints.

You would have to drop any unique key or primary key constraints on the table to allow duplicates in the respective columns.

Comment: I am Mysql database design expert and I would say that you are absolutely correct.